# Do I need to know express to use Javascript?

Tags: javascript, express

is it necessary to know express in order to use to learn javascript?

I am learning express with git and vs code and struggling to run the code in vs code - I don't know how to do it how to open the URL.
And in vs code "require" doesn't work properly (error):

```
let express = require("express");
```

Thank you for your responses,
-l

Comment: No. There are many Javascript environments who have nothing to do with Express

Comment: you should also have a look at node.js https://nodejs.org/en/about/

Answer (score 0):

No, Express knowledge is not required for learning javascript.

**[Express](https://expressjs.com/)** is a minimal and flexible Node.js web application framework that provides a robust set of features for web and mobile applications. which is written in javascript. In order to use express you should have basic knowledge of javascript and ES5  features for Node.js.

Check your package.json for information whether you have installed express as dependency or not.